# Auto-incrementing Django DateField

Tags: django, date, django-models

How does one create a DateField, which automatically increments by 1 day in the way that the **pk** field does?

For example, I would create a new object, this would be of 16/04/2017, the next object would be of 17/04/2017, even if they are both submitted on the same day.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about override the model's `save` method like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from django.db import models


class MyModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()  # the below method will NOT work if auto_now/auto_now_add are set to True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # count how many objects are already saved with the date this current object is saved
        date_gte_count = MyModel.objects.filter(date__gte=self.date).count()
        if date_gte_count:
            # there are some objects saved with the same or greater date. Increase the day by this number.
            self.date += timedelta(days=date_gte_count)
        # save object in db
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Of course, the above can be implemented using [Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/). The [`pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save) one.

Comment: This implementation doesn't quite work because when we create the second object, assuming that the first is set to the current date, then it increases by one day. But when we make the third, it simply looks for one that equals its date, therefore it increases by one and now we have two which have the same date. I have refined your answer in my answer, thanks nik.

Comment: @maxcodes Hmmm... You're right. Haven't think of that. I have modified my answer to avoid the `while` loop :) No need to make multiple `.exists()` queries in the database. Check now, please.

Comment: In fact, this answer does seem to work and is much better with fewer queries! Thank you @nik_m.

Answer (score 0):

So I worked this out using parts of [Nik_m's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2231182/nik-m) answer and also some of my knowledge.

I essentially made a while loop which kept iterating over and adding a day, as opposed to Nik_m's answer which doesn't work after the third object due to a lack of iteration.

```
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    same_date_obj = Challenge.objects.filter(date=self.date)

    if same_date_obj.exists():
        while True:
            if Challenge.objects.filter(date=self.date).exists():
                self.date += timedelta(days=1)
            else:
                break
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

EDIT: This answer is no longer valid, it requires a while loop and thus an indefinite amount of queries. @Nik_m's modified answer is better.